# Linq query in ASP.net MVC accessing another table through a table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, linq

I am trying to access a value from one table through another.  I have a table PainCategories that contains a PainCategoryId and a table Triage that contains a PainCategoryId.  I am trying to run a query through Triage to compare that Id value to the value in the PainCategory table.  The triage table contains multiple rows that have the PainCategoryId of 1 and there is only one PainCategoryId = to 1 in the PainCategory table.  If anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my linq in my controller:

```
 tt.painCats = db.PainCategories.ToList().Where(p => p.CompanyId == CompanyId);

tt.triages = db.Triages.ToList().Where(t => t.PainCategoryId == tt.painCats.
Contains(t.PainCategoryId)); //Error is in this line because it is just not done
//right with the Contains.
```

Model for triage:

```
public class Triage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int PainCategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual PainCategory PainCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Model for PainCategory:

```
public class PainCategory
    {
        public PainCategory()
        {
            Triages = new HashSet<Triage>();
        }
        public int PainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Triage> Triages { get; set; }
    }
```

View for the razor calls:

```
foreach (var item in Model.painCats)
        {
            @Html.Label(item.Title)<br/>
            foreach(var tri in Model.triages)
            {
                @Html.RadioButton(tri.PainCategory.Title, tri.Order)
                @Html.Label(tri.Description)<br/>
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us the structure of the classes for `PainCatogories` and `Triages`.

Comment: I edited it with the models.

Comment: So this works but it only returns all the triage with paincategory = to 3 (which is like 6 rows), but I need it to return the ones = to 2 and 1 as well.

Comment: tt.triages = db.Triages.ToList().Where(t => t.PainCategoryId == tt.painCats.Select(x => x.PainCategoryId).FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shawn,

Could you try

```
// This doesn't work because db.Triages is not List<T>, 
// the Contains method only applies to Lists
tt.triages = db.Triages.ToList().Where(t => tt.painCats.Contains(t.PainCategoryId));
```

Update:

Try using the Any operator, like this:

```
// The Any method is a core linq method and is implemented for both Enumerable and Queryable
tt.triages = db.Triages.ToList().Where(t => tt.painCats.Any(cat => t.PainCategoryId == cat.PainCategoryId));
```

Comment: Says that the IEnumerable<Model.PainCategories>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload...

Comment: That works perfect for getting each paintcategoryId from the database.  I edited the code, I am trying to Print out a painCategory Title and then the PaincategoryId under that Title, then the next PainCategory Title with that titles PaintCategoryId under that.  Any idea?

Comment: Why not open another question with your view model code? That will be easier to look at and make this question more useful for future reference.